# Is there a generic way to get page source of current page / Sitecore.Context.Item without downloading it?

Tags: sitecore-api

Is there a generic way to get the HTML page source of the current Sitecore.Context.Item without downloading it, so, it will cover all (WebForms/Sitecore.Mvc/JSS etc.) scenarios?

Is it possible to get the HTML page source somewhere in pipeline processors etc.?

Comment: If you are looking for a solution which will cover all Sitecore implementation type then good to create REST API which use WebClient to return page HTML by passing the Page url https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/c%23+get+html+source+from+url

Comment: Thanks, @AmitKumar, but I'm wondering if it is possible to get an HTML source of the current context item somewhere in Sitecore pipelines, etc.

Comment: In pipeline once item resolved then using WebClient you can get html based upon your page template

Comment: A assume it will lead to a circular issue:
1. Requesting http://mystites/itemA
2. Context item is itemA
3. Downloading http://mystites/itemA somewhere in httpRequestBegin, httpRequestEnd or httpRequestProcessed, but it will redirect to p. 1, right?

Comment: Yes. Due to this in first place I told it to be outside of Sitecore. Every request will come to your pipeline, you may be store page item in session and place filter with page item template type.